# Powershell - Export SQL to XML to file - no clean output

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell

I am trying to export a sql query to an xml file with Powershell using the below script:

```
$SQLResult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -MaxCharLength ([int]::MaxValue) -AbortOnError -EncryptConnection -ConnectionTimeout $TIMEOUT -Database $Database -ServerInstance $SQL_SERVER_FULLNAME_SOURCE -Username $SQL_ACCOUNT_NAME_SOURCE -Password $SQL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_SOURCE -Query $QUERY 
$PropertyName = ($SQLResult | Get-Member -MemberType Property | Where {$_.Name -like "XML*"}).Name
$SQLResult.$PropertyName | Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -Force
```

It should generate a file like below:

```
<vendors>
  <vendor>
    <administration>YIT</administration>
    <FISCALCODE>804658055B01</FISCALCODE>
    <accountNumber>10001</accountNumber>
    <Offset_LedgerAccount></Offset_LedgerAccount>
    <name>Comp Europe B.V.</name>
    <shortName>Comp Europe B.V.</shortName>
    <TAXEXEMPTNUMBER>NL801238055B01</TAXEXEMPTNUMBER>
    <DefaultDescription></DefaultDescription>
    <invoiceType>Non-PO CEE-FN-ACQ</invoiceType>
    <IBAN>NL57MHCB0212303590</IBAN>
    <CUSTOMERACCOUNT></CUSTOMERACCOUNT>
    <TAXITEMGROUP></TAXITEMGROUP>
    <IncludeOrderReference>Unknown</IncludeOrderReference>
    <lineText></lineText>
    <lines>Unknown</lines>
  </vendor>
  <vendor>
    <administration>YIT</administration>
    <FISCALCODE>03840123961</FISCALCODE>
    <accountNumber>20001</accountNumber>
    <Offset_LedgerAccount></Offset_LedgerAccount>
    <name>4ABCD - For Marketing s.r.l.</name>
    <shortName>4ABCD-FOR MARKETING</shortName>
    <TAXEXEMPTNUMBER>03840123961</TAXEXEMPTNUMBER>
    <DefaultDescription></DefaultDescription>
    <invoiceType>Purchase invoice</invoiceType>
    <IBAN>IT93M0306912330615256048252</IBAN>
    <CUSTOMERACCOUNT></CUSTOMERACCOUNT>
    <TAXITEMGROUP></TAXITEMGROUP>
    <IncludeOrderReference>Unknown</IncludeOrderReference>
    <lineText></lineText>
    <lines>Unknown</lines>
  </vendor>
<vendors>
```

In real it can contain a few thousand records.

The problem with the various other options that I used is that the output file is either truncated, or it contains double quotes. With the above script suddenly extra spaces are added that are repeated every certain block of output. If I run the query in MSMS it generates a perfectly clean result that I can save as .xml file.

```
<vendor>
        <administration>YIT</administration>
        <FISCALCODE>0381230961</FISCALCODE>
        <accountNumber>20001</accountNumber>
        <Offset_LedgerAccount/>
        <name>4ABCD - For Marketing s.r.l.</name>
        <shortName>4ABCD-FOR MARKETING</shortName>
        <TAXEXEMPTNUMBER>03840123961</TAXEXEMPTNUMBER>
        <DefaultDescription/>
        <invoiceType>Purchase invoice</invoiceType>
        <IBAN>IT93M03069121238252</IBAN>
        <CUST OMERACCOUNT>< CUSTOMERACCOUNT><TAXITEMGROUP>< TAXITEMGROUP><IncludeOrderReference>Unknown< IncludeOrderReference><lineText>< lineText>
```

As you can see above it starts okay but then suddenly it starts adding a single space to certain nodes, not to all. Then it continues okay for some records and then a gain a line with a single space in some of the nodes.

I tried various solutions but none of them seem to work for me. Can somebody explain what I am doing wrong? The actual query I use is below.

```
SELECT 
v.[DATAAREAID] AS [administration]
,v.[FISCALCODE]
,v.[VENDORACCOUNTNUMBER] AS [accountNumber]
,v.[DEFAULTOFFSETLEDGERACCOUNTDISPLAYVALUE] AS [Offset_LedgerAccount]
,v.[VENDORORGANIZATIONNAME] AS [name]
,v.[VENDORSEARCHNAME] AS [shortName]
,CASE WHEN LEFT(v.[TAXEXEMPTNUMBER],2)='IT' THEN RIGHT(v.[TAXEXEMPTNUMBER],LEN(v.[TAXEXEMPTNUMBER])-2) ELSE v.[TAXEXEMPTNUMBER] END AS [TAXEXEMPTNUMBER]
,ISNULL(v.[NOTES],'') AS [DefaultDescription]
,ISNULL(ipvp.[INVOICETYPENAME],'') AS [invoiceType]
,ISNULL(vba.[IBAN],'') AS [IBAN]
,ISNULL(c.[CUSTOMERACCOUNT],'') AS [CUSTOMERACCOUNT]
,ISNULL(itc.[TAXITEMGROUP],'') AS [TAXITEMGROUP]
,'Unknown' AS [IncludeOrderReference]
,v.[DESTINATIONCODE] AS [lineText]
,'Unknown' AS [lines]
  FROM [dbo].[RetailVendVendorV3Staging] v
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AXTip_ParametersVendTableStaging] ipvp ON v.[VENDORACCOUNTNUMBER]=ipvp.[VENDORACCOUNT] AND v.[DATAAREAID]=ipvp.[DATAAREAID]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[VendVendorBankAccountStaging] vba ON vba.[DATAAREAID]=v.[DATAAREAID] AND vba.[VENDORACCOUNTNUMBER]=v.[VENDORACCOUNTNUMBER] AND  vba.[VENDORBANKACCOUNTID]=v.[BANKACCOUNTID]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CustCustomerV3Staging] c ON c.[VENDORACCOUNT]=v.[VENDORACCOUNTNUMBER] AND v.[DATAAREAID]=c.[DATAAREAID]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AXTip_ImportTaxcodeStaging] itc ON itc.[ACCOUNTRELATION]=v.[VENDORACCOUNTNUMBER] AND itc.[DATAAREAID]=v.[DATAAREAID] AND itc.[EXTERNALTAXCODE]='I'
  WHERE v.[DATAAREAID] ='YIT' AND v.[FISCALCODE]!=''
    FOR XML PATH('vendor'), root('vendors')
```

Comment: Where are you exporting the data to the xml file? I see no reference of it. Also could you add a snippet of your current output? So we could see what needs to change.

Comment: Post the result, don't describe it.

Comment: The query already results into xml-output. The result is written to a file with "Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -Force". I will add a sniplet of the out to the original post.

Comment: Ah I see, the SqlServer module already has a built-in xml object from the query then? It might be that there is an issue with that component, perhaps try to output the value into the console and see if those spaces are also there?

Comment: Thanks but I think that the way that I try to export xml is just not the way to do it in Powershell. I copied the method as explained on this website and that works perfectly: [link](https://stuartsplace.com/information-technology/programming/powershell/powershell-and-sql-server-exporting-data-xml)

Answer (score 0):

I read quite a lot of issues using the method that I used in the opening post. The method described in the link below seems a more "powershell" way to generate an xml file using sql-data. I copied this method and it works well.

[stuartsplace.com: powershell-and-sql-server-exporting-data-xml](https://stuartsplace.com/information-technology/programming/powershell/powershell-and-sql-server-exporting-data-xml)